# Python: range() and non-consumable generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, generator

In Python 3 (2), the `range` (`xrange`) function returns a generator which yields consecutive integers, e.g.

```
g = range(5)
print(g)  # Prints range(0, 5)
t = tuple(g)
print(t)  # Prints (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Here, `tuple(g)` constructs a tuple by looping over the generator `g` and storing each yielded number. I can also construct a generator from the tuple, e.g.

```
# like this
g2 = iter(t)
t2 = tuple(g2)
# or like this
g3 = (n for n in t)
t3 = tuple(g3)
```

There is however a big difference between the original `g` and the homecrafted `g2` and `g3`, which we see if we try to construct a second tuple:

```
tuple(g)   # Works as before
tuple(g2)  # Produces an empty tuple !
tuple(g3)  # Produces an empty tuple !
```

Thus `g2` and `g3` (unlike `g`) are "consumed" on iteration.

Is there an easy way to produce custom, non-consumable generators? My guess is that neither bare generator expressions nor bare functions that `yield`s can be used.

Comment: range is not a generator ...

Comment: What you are describing is an iterable, not a generator.  Google for information about Python iterables and "iterator protocol".